# SELECT* mssql + php

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I wanna to show the results from this:

```
require 'connection.php';
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM tadatable";    

/* Execute the query. */    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);    

if ( $stmt )    
{    
       $id = $stmt['id']; 
      echo"<td>".$stmt['name']."</td>"; 
}     echo"<td>".$stmt['name2']."</td>"; 
else     
{    
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

No data executed. Just blank page, can you please see what is wrong?
MSSQL/PHP/ works fine...

Comment: may be syntax error in your page . ON error debug mode . put this in page top  ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting('E_ALL');

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php ..

Answer (score 0):

> **sqlsrv_query**
>   Returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if
>   an error occurred.

After you've successfully executed the query with `sqlsrv_query` you can fetch the results, by using `sqlsrv_fetch_array` or use `sqlsrv_fetch_array` to get first result directly.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);   
if($stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
// loop results with `sqlsrv_fetch_array`
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['id'].", ".$row['name'].", ".$row['name2']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: So why downvote this answer, because you've got a downvote on your not-working answers... ? It's actually the only working answer there is at this moment...  JEZUS!

Answer (score -1):

I feel you missed scrollable array.

Alter the following line.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
```

Comment: bro its not required ... Check This First. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php  
require 'connection.php';

//$serverName = "(local)";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ){  
 echo "Could not connect.\n";  
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  


$tsql = "SELECT * FROM tadatable";

if( sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql))  
{  
      //echo "Statement executed.";  

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     echo $row['id'].", ".$row['name'].", ".$row['name2']."<br />";
   }

}   
else  
{  
      echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  


sqlsrv_close($conn);  
?>
```

> **For Reference :** http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php
>
> **Example #1 Retrieving an associative array.**